# How to combine two dataframes into pairplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 in Python, transformed from a numpy array in which df1 has 50 rows and 8 columns and df2 10 rows and 8 columns as well, and I would like to use pairplot to see these values. I have made something like this:

```
    df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
    df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
    sns.pairplot(df1)
    sns.pairplot(df2)
    plt.show()
```

But I would like that the points or histograms of the df2 to appear superimpose, for example, in red color to the df1 points which are in blue. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate problem I use `iris` dataset.
First produce 2 dataframes:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df1 = iris[iris.species =='setosa']
df2 = iris[iris.species =='versicolor']
```

We have now Your starting point. Then concatenate dataframes and plot the result:

```
df12 = df1.append(df2)

g = sns.pairplot(df12, hue="species")
```

use `hue` parameter to separate points by color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `hue` parameter in seaborn you can choose column that will differ them.

```
sns.pairplot(joined_df,hue='special_column_to_differ_df')
```

But you will have to join them first.